# How to get username from authentication prompt popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, basic-authentication

I have SharePoint Online classic page which has some custom JavaScript and jQuery scripts implemented and third party .NET app requiring some basic auth. When the user visits the page he is prompted to enter username and password. How can I get the username from this prompt? Prompt is standard and looks like this (picture is not mine)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint's javascript API to retrieve the current user's information.

```
_spPageContextInfo.userId
```

see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx

Another suggestion is to use the API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getCurrentUser, "sp.js");
 
var currentUser;
 
function getCurrentUser(){
var ctx= new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
ctx.load(currentUser);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
 
function onSuccess() {
alert(currentUser.get_title()); // Domain\Account 
alert(currentUser.get_email());
document.getElementById('userLogin').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
}
 
function onFailure() {
alert('request failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
 
</script>
 
<div>Currently Logged User:
    <span id="userLogin"></span>
</div>
```

MS reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code

Comment: I'll try that, if it returns the domain\account this is what I need.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it does not return what I need. In particular it does not return the actual domain under the account is registered to. Probably because this is old account registered when there was only SharePoint 2013. For now I haven't found a way how to get the original domain\username used in SharePoint 2013 from SharePoint Online. This is the reason I'm trying to get this information from the authentication prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested in this I found a way to get the user principal name with microsoft graph API  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=mailnickname,onpremisesUserprincipalName was the actual request I needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).